# PHP Regular Expression select between characters or to end of string

Tags: php, regex

I have been working on this problem for several days and it's starting to drive me crazy.  I'm comfortable using regular expressions but this one thing seems to be escaping me.
I need to match a string between a set of characters if they exist otherwise it should match to the end of the line.

For example:
I'm just trying to get "content" out of the following example:

```
$str1="title:content @description"
$str2="title:content"
preg_match("/:(.*?)[(@)|(:)|(\*)]?$/",$str1,$content);
preg_match("/:(.*?)[(@)|(:)|(\*)]?$/",$str2,$content);
```

$str1 outputs:"content @description"

$str2 outputs:"content"

note: the strings may be in a different order or may not have a special character (@,:,or *) in it or they might have one so there's no "end of string" character that will be common besides "end of line".

I've tried every combination i can think of to make the entire "or" statement conditional and read a ton of posts with similar but not quite the same question.

Comment: Where you say "$str1 outputs: ..." do you mean that's what it's currently doing, or that's what you WANT it to do?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the `[...]` notation. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

```
preg_match("/:(.*?)(?:[@:*]|$)/", $str1, $content);
```

(note that the match ends at one of `@:*` *or* end-of-string, using `|`; your version has the `[@:*]` optional, but makes the end-of-string mandatory.)

or simply:

```
preg_match("/:([^@:*]*)/", $str1, $content);
```

(meaning "a colon, followed by zero or more characters that aren't in `@:*`").